# Changing a to-many relationship to a to-one with Core Data migration

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data, ios5, migration

I've come across a bit of a problem when I try and migrate my data model from old to new. I've been searching the web and trying to find a solution to this issue for a couple of weeks now, but still no luck.

This is what my data model looked like like before:

```
A <<--->> B
  <<--->> C
```

And after:

```
A <<---> B
  <<---> C
```

As you can see, the relationships between the entities A to B and A to C changed from a many-to-many relationship to a many-to-one. The problem is getting the migration to work. If I try it using light weight migration, I get this in the console (along with a lot of other stuff):

> Can not map from a to-many to a to-one relationship.

This makes sense when considering the documentation. So I guessed that I needed to use a mapping model and a custom migration policy to handle the relationship change. If I use the mapping model that is automatically generated, I just get an "Unresolved error" and about half way through the log, it says that it can't find the mapping model for migration. I'm assuming that this is like a generic error description as a trivial change to the model (i.e. changing the name of something) works (meaning that it can indeed find the mapping model). So my question is: how do I get the mapping model to migrate the store correctly? And can you please be descriptive as to what I need to do to accomplish this? I'm guessing I'll need to use this method:

```
- (BOOL)createRelationshipsForDestinationInstance:(NSManagedObject *)dInstance entityMapping:(NSEntityMapping *)mapping manager:(NSMigrationManager *)manager error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)error
```

in the custom policy, but what code do I need in this method to make it work (if you can even just generalise on it)?

By the way, I'm using Xcode 4.3.2 and the minimum iOS requirement for this application is iOS 5.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The first question that arises is - exactly which *one* of the to-many `B`s and `C`s do you want a given `A` to be left with after the migration?

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified that. There is only ever one 'B' or 'C' entity that relates to 'A'. Hence the reason to change to a to-one relationship type. So there should be a clear way of picking the right objects to preserve in the migration.

Comment: Did you have any luck with this?